# PHP session message in the same page is not displaying

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
<?php
  require_once 'init.php';
  include 'includes/head.php';
  include 'includes/navigation.php';

  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

  $error = false;
  $msg = "";
  $msg2 = "";
  $msg3 = "";
if($_POST){
  $name = preg_replace('/^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?=\s)/', '',
  (isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name'] != ''?sanitize($_POST['name']):''));
  $phone = preg_replace('/^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?=\s)/', '',
  (isset($_POST['phone']) && $_POST['phone'] != ''?sanitize($_POST['phone']):''));
  $email = preg_replace('/^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?=\s)/', '',
  (isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] != ''?sanitize($_POST['email']):''));
  $message = preg_replace('/^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?=\s)/', '',
  (isset($_POST['message']) && $_POST['message'] != ''?sanitize($_POST['message']):''));
  include_once 'PHPMailer/Exception.php';
  include_once 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
  include_once 'PHPMailer/SMTP.php';
  $mail = new PHPMailer();
  $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
  $mail->IsSMTP();
  $mail->Mailer = 'smtp';
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->Host = '';
  $mail->Port = 465;
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
  $mail->addAddress("");

  $mail->Username = "";
  $mail->Password = "";

  $mail->IsHTML(true); 
  $mail->SingleTo = true;

  $mail->setFrom($email, $email);
  $mail->Subject = "Order";
  $mail->Body = "<style>
                 h5{
                 background-color: #eaeaea;
                 padding-top: 8px;
                 padding-bottom: 8px;
                 font-weight: bold;
                 text-decoration: underline;
                 text-align: center;
                 margin-bottom: 10px;
                 }
                 table{
                   border-collapse: collapse;
                   width: 100%;
                 }
                 td, th{
                   border: 1px solid #dddddd;
                   text-align: left;
                   padding: 8px;
                 }
                 </style>
                 <h5>User Details</h5>
                 <table>
                 <tr>
                 <th>Name</th>
                 <td>$name</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                 <th>Email</th>
                 <td>$email</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                 <th>Phone</th>
                 <td>$phone</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                 <th>Message</th>
                 <td>$message</td>
                 </tr>
                 </table>";

//form validation
if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['phone']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['message'])){
  $error = true;
  $msg = "<ul><li class='text-danger'>Please fill all the blanks.</li></ul>";
}

if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && !empty($_POST['email'])){
    $error = true;
    $msg2 = "<ul><li class='text-danger'>Please enter a valid email.</li></ul>";
}

if($error === false && $mail->Send()){
  $_SESSION['msg'] = "<p class='text-success'>Email has been sent.</p>";
  header('Location: contact.php');
 }
}
  ?>


        <?=(isset($msg)?$msg:'');?>
        <?=(isset($msg2)?$msg2:'');?>

        <?php
         if(isset($_SESSION["msg"])){
           echo $_SESSION['msg'];
             unset($_SESSION['msg']);
           }
         }
```

The code works well except the session message. `session_start();` is in init.php. I am trying to display a message using session in the same page, but the message is never shown...

I tried removing `unset($_SESSION['msg']);` but I faced a new problem which is the message will not be removed when refreshing the page or moving to another page. It will stay there unless I restart dns (WAMP). How to fix this issue?

Comment: Please read this: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).